# Vim and indentation with brackets/braces

Tags: vim

When editing JavaScript, I usually have to do this:

```
function myFunc() {
  // func body here
}
```

I've tried a few bracket-closing plugins like AutoClose and vrackets, but when I come to code like above, they all do this:

```
function myFunc() {<CR>
|}
```

How can I make Vim insert a  before the bracket when I go to new line, and indent the cursor properly like so:

```
function myFunc() {<CR>
  |<CR>
}
```

Is there like a plugin or something that does this?

Comment: The [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) plugin provides an option for this IIRC.

Comment: @Randy: My vim config must be cursed or something. delimitMate won't do CR expansion...

Comment: Although this thread quite old, I would still like to add that delimitMate does have an option to do this: just add `let g:delimitMate_expand_cr = 1` to your .vimrc. See `:help delimitMate` for more options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
```

Comment: For one reason or another, it doesn't do anything for me... Could be a conflict with a plugin.

Comment: Hard to tell. What do you mean by "it doesn't do anything for me"? Does it do something? What?

Comment: I mean it doesn't make any difference whatsoever whether I have that in vimrc or not... Which is weird. My guess is that some plugin overrides the mapping.

Comment: Now I notice (without the above mapping in vimrc), I get `<S***_SelectCompletion(1)>` (where *** is not readable) displayed for a fraction of a second when I press Enter in insert mode. EDIT: Yeah, SuperTab is remapping <CR> to handle selection of autocomplete candidates.

Comment: After removing SuperTab, the above mapping sill doesn't do anything differently...

Comment: Do you mean that `Ctrl`+`Return` doesn't input at least two carriage returns?

Comment: I feel so stupid... I totally mistook <C-Return> for <CR>... Ok, I get it. In my case, with all indentation plugins, `inoremap <C-Return> <CR><Esc>O` works just fine. I went with this solution in the end.

Comment: `<Tab>` may be not the best here, because for python code, use `<Space>` is recommended.

Comment: @Voldikss, everything is contextual in Vim. The question is about JavaScript, so is the answer.

Comment: For me `:inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><Esc>kS` worked better.

Answer (score 6):

I use this mapping in combination with AutoClose:

```
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O
```

No special key combination is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I've discovered that you can actually map key combination like that a few months after posting the question.

Comment: This finally did it for me, and I also use it with vim-autoclose.

Answer (score 1):

I maybe way off base, but have you tried using the abbreviate command?

```
:ab {} {<cr>}<esc>ko
```

Of course, I have smartindent on and I would have to type {} for it to complete, but it works for me.

Comment: So close, but doesn't work when I have bracket auto-closing on... I can create a different abbreviation, like `fnc` and have that expand to what you have there, as a stop-gap solution. If nobody comes up with a better solution, I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried map the whole function, such as

`inoremap ,4 function() {}<left><enter><esc>O`