# Vim auto indents curly brackets wrong

Tags: javascript, vim

I have smart indent and auto indent turned on, but it still acts weird with curly brackets (at least in JavaScript). If i type:

```
if(x==y){
```

then I get this:

```
if(x==y){
  }
```

And I have no idea why. I constantly have to backspace once to get the normal:

```
if(x == y){
  //yay!
}
```

syntax. Would it at all be possible to have it also put the cursor inside the if block with the cursor at the first `/` in the comment above?

Here's my current `.vimrc` file.

```
"Color syntaxing of course
syntax on

"colorscheme molokai

:colors molokai

"Lots of undo history... just in case
set history=700

"Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread

"highlight the current line
set cul

"set color of the highlighted line
hi CursorLine term=none cterm=none ctermbg=234

"auto indent
set autoindent
set smartindent

"Soft tabs FTW
set expandtab
set smarttab                                        

"Size of the (soft) tabs
set shiftwidth=2                                    
set softtabstop=2

"Show line numbers
set number

"Set line number colors to something other than that god awful orange
hi LineNr ctermfg=234 ctermbg=black


"Change the color of the matching brackets
highlight MatchParen cterm=bold ctermfg=black ctermbg=DarkYellow

"Keep at least 5 lines of space above and below and then left and right
set scrolloff=5
set sidescrolloff=5

hi StatusLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=darkgreen ctermfg=white

"Scrolling with your mouse!
set ttymouse=xterm2
set mouse=a

let g:molokai_original = 1

" Find file in current directory and edit it.
function! Find(name)
  let l:list=system("find . -name '".a:name."' | perl -ne 'print \"$.\\t$_\"'")
  let l:num=strlen(substitute(l:list, "[^\n]", "", "g"))
  if l:num < 1
    echo "'".a:name."' not found"
    return
  endif
  if l:num != 1
    echo l:list
    let l:input=input("Which ? (CR=nothing)\n")
    if strlen(l:input)==0
      return
    endif
    if strlen(substitute(l:input, "[0-9]", "", "g"))>0
      echo "Not a number"
      return
    endif
    if l:input<1 || l:input>l:num
      echo "Out of range"
      return
    endif
    let l:line=matchstr("\n".l:list, "\n".l:input."\t[^\n]*")
  else
    let l:line=l:list
  endif
  let l:line=substitute(l:line, "^[^\t]*\t./", "", "")
  execute ":e ".l:line
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Find :call Find("<args>")
```

Comment: What language are you using? You code example is small enough that it could be lots of things.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I added a tag and added text to the start. I'm almost always in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the vim javascript indent plugin [JavaScript Indent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081), which gave me very satisfying results when programming javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Vim can do that by default. See [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621173/vim-and-indentation-with-brackets-braces/9622399#9622399) for a good enough workaround.

EDIT

The mapping is like a macro that replays your keypresses instantly:

1. starting point in *insert* mode, `|` is your cursor

   ```
   if(x == y){|}
   ```
2. `<CR>`

   ```
   if(x == y){
   |}
   ```
3. `<CR>`

   ```
   if(x == y){

   |}
   ```
4. `<C-o>k` (could be `<Esc>k`)

   ```
   if(x == y){
   |
   }
   ```
5. `<Tab>`

   ```
   if(x == y){
     |
   }
   ```

It's very dumb, actually, and should work anywhere you have a `Ctrl` key and a `Return` key.

ENDEDIT

Comment: I added that but I can't see a difference? I'm not completely new to vim, but im not a vim wizard yet either. Am I doing something wrong? Does this not automatically work or something when I hit return?

Comment: No, you simply hit `Ctrl`+`Return` between your `{}` to get exactly the result you want.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be doing anything differently? I just added `inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>` then quit vim, and started it up again. I then typed `if(x == y){` got `if(x == y){}` then, inside the `{}` I pressed (on a Mac) `ctrl+return`. I also tried `ctrl+fn+return` which would trigger an "enter". I noticed the other person who commented on your post had the same issue. Was it ever fully resolved?

Comment: I'm on a Mac too and it has been working without issues (MacVim & Vim) since my switch from TextMate a year and a half ago. In the end it worked for the other person too: he was just hitting `<Return>` instead of `<C-Return>`. This mapping is as simple as possible. It's only executing a short series of simple keypresses. I don't know what could break it beside having another conflicting mapping somewhere: try `:verbose imap <c-cr>`. Just to be clear, are you in *insert* mode?